# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy corriendo el siguiente codigo sencillo para Python 3.10.9:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

El modulo subprocess está en el directorio del módulo porque ya lo verifiqué:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no hay forma de que termine de correr. Esta es la respuesta que consigo del terminal:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas por defecto el comando ls no esta instalado en Windows que veo que es donde lo estas corriendo. Deberias de probar con dir, que es su equivalente para windows

Comment: Hola. Gracias por responder. Acabo de correr en efecto el comando "dir", pero el error es exactamente igual. De hecho en el terminal en el que estoy, puedo correr comandos de linux sin problemas.

Comment: `ls` no es un ejecutable independiente; es un comando reconocido y ejecutado por el shell que ocupes.

Comment: `ls` es un alias de `Get-ChildItem`, que es un comando interno de `Powershell` y no un ejecutable como tal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregando shell=True:

```python
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)
```

Al parecer este tipo de llamadas que fallan tienen que ver con las variables de entorno del sistema (PATH), por lo que si utilizas shell=True no tendrás que lidiar con ello.

Por otro lado, ¿no estás en windows? Deberías de usar el comando 'dir':

```js
subprocess.run(["dir"], shell=True)
```

O de lo contrario no funcionará, ls es un comando de linux, no de Windows.

Comment: Listo amigo. Ahora si funcionó! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Dale al vote up y respuesta respondida :D